# Win 10 USB install error, "...cannot create or find existing partition."

Tags: windows-10, installation

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. New WD HDD, partitioned as GPT with both EaseUs & Cmd prompt as primary. Tried install from both USB 2.0 & 3.0, same results. Disabled Secure boot with Legacy enabled, same results. Copied setup files from USB to HDD OS partition, same error msg.. Created USB boot both with Win Media Creator and Rufus, same result. Error msg states "check setup log", will this help & where is it, nothing found on USB. This isn't my first rodeo but I've never encountered this... Thank you!!!

Comment: Have you disconnected all hard drives except the one you are installing to?

Comment: Only new WD HDD attached with Win10 USB flash drive. Tried removing USB during install then reinserting it as suggested by someone on the web but no luck, same error msg.. Did this same install process last year on desktop pc with a Seagate Barracuda HDD and had no issues at all. I'm at a total loss as to what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved!! Attempted to once again copy Win10 setup files to HDD but it still wouldn't boot. All of the instructions on resolving through cmd prompt were flawed as they instruct you to create a MBR instead of a GPT which will work on older bios machines but it must be GPT on UEFI boot machines. Going through the process did give me an idea tho' so I deleted all partitions on the HDD and left the space "unallocated". Sure enough the Win10 setup on USB worked. Hope this helps someone else.